# Cordova camera getPicture is lossless compressing even when quality is 100

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, base64, image-compression

Hello friends In my project, I'm able to capture the image via camera or gallery the size of the Image file vary to 5-6 MB based on the quality of camera or user selected image.Then I have to upload it on server.

The requirement is, before upload the file on remote server, I want to apply lossless compression on image to reduce the file size to 2-3MB so it will save internet cost of user & and my server space as well.

without using `resize` image. how can I do this?.

I have the user upload a Image. This is my code.

```
$scope.addImage = function (source) {
            $rootScope.ionPopup.close();
            var src = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            if (source == 'PHOTOLIBRARY')
                src = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            var options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: src,
                allowEdit: false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 350,
                targetHeight: 350,
                //popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                correctOrientation: true
            };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                uploadImage(imageData);

            }, function (err) {
                // error
            });
        };
        var uploadImage = function (imageData) {
            $scope.orderImages.push(imageData);
            $scope.orderImagesList.push({ImageString: imageData});
        };
```

`imageData` is the base64 encoded image.

How can I compress that base64 encoded image ?

can someone help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `targetHeight`, and `targetWidth` options should change the resulting file size. I recently used:

```
quality: 90, 
targetWidth: 900,
targetHeight: 900,
```

to get a huge 10MB image file to scale down to about 200KB. Keep in mind that:

> Photos selected from the device's gallery are not downscaled to a
>   lower quality, even if a quality parameter is specified.

Source: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html